# John the ripper output formatting

Tags: passwords, john-the-ripper

I'm supposed to crack some passwords from a file. I've done `john pwlist.lst > passwords.txt` which is outputting the files into my txt file.

I'd like to make it such that when John is cracking the passwords hashed with SHA224, it outputs them into the .txt file in the format `{hash}:{password}`

Example: `b13eaa5bcb49d6c7ff9106b61ea5dcc24a75835ae11183f4ab203929:go`

Comment: What is it outputting now?

Comment: It's just outputting {password}   {user}
Example: somePassword  (?)

Comment: I think the pot file contains the hash/password pairing. Have you looked there? Otherwise, I think you'll need to script something to get the precise output you're looking for.

Comment: You have the password. Getting the hash of that password should be easy.

Comment: I have not. I'll give that a shot, only thing is I'm unsure of where I find the pot file, but I'll look into that, thank you

Comment: Maybe modify the output file with regex